# Added field not published to client?

Tags: meteor

I'm doing an aggregation in Meteor where I'm trying to find 'thingies' within a given distance and publish it to the client:

```
Meteor.publish("thingieSearch", function(userId) {
  check(userId, String);
  var subscription = this;
  var thingies = {};
  var userId = this.userId;
  var usrAcc = Meteor.users.findOne({_id: userId});
  var db = MongoInternals.defaultRemoteCollectionDriver().mongo.db;
  var pipeline = [{
    $geoNear: {
      near: usrAcc.profile.location.geometry.coordinates,
      distanceField: "calculatedDistance",
      spherical: true,
      limit: 100,
      distanceMultiplier: 3959.2,
      maxDistance: 0.075,
      query: {
        "status": "started",
        "owner": {$ne: userId} },
    }
  }];
  db.collection("thingies").aggregate(
    pipeline,
    Meteor.bindEnvironment(
      function (err, result) {
        console.log('result', result);
        _.each(result, function (r) {
          chases[r._id] = r;
          subscription.added("thingieSearch", r._id, {
            chase: r
          });
        })
      }
    )
  );
  subscription.ready();
});
```

When I do a console.log on the server side, it looks correct, the 'distanceField' that I specified as 'calculatedDistance' is calculated and shown as a field.

On the client side, I subscribe to this publication and I can see the thingies but I can't see the 'calculatedDistance' field.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things here.

1) Your publication will not reactively update data to the client, since you are using `mongodb` remote collection driver. If you intend it to be a non-reactive then you can use a meteor method instead of publication and call the method whenever `userId` changes.

2) I think you are using `thingies` collection on the client side and not seeing the `calculatedDistance` field. You need to create a client only collection (`thingieSearch`) to access the custom published results like this,

```
//On client side only
thingieSearch = new Mongo.Collection("thingieSearch");

thingieSearch.findOne(); // After the publication, you should be able to see the results with calculatedDistance
```

You should use whatever name you passed inside the `subscription.added` block to create collection. For example, if your publication has

```
subscription.added("thingieWithCalculateField", r._id, { chase: r });
```

you should do

```
//On client side only
thingieWithCalculateField = new Mongo.Collection("thingieWithCalculateField");
// instead of thingieSearch = new Mongo.Collection("thingieSearch");
```

See the `counts-by-room` publication in the [`Meteor.publish` documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_publish) for more details.

Comment: Thanks @Kishor, I'll take a look.